# QR code text with line breaks not working in browser text box

Tags: qr-code

I'm trying to create a QR Code that when scanned with a 3D barcode scanner, will enter text with line breaks into a browser text box. This is what I have and it works perfectly in Word/Notepad. But when I try to scan it into a text box in a browser it opens a new tab after the first line break and tries to search google downloads.

```
=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=" & "Line%201%0A%0ALine%202%0ALine%203%0ALine%204%0A%0ALine%205")
```

Is this something wrong with the code or with how the scanner is programmed?

I have tried many different generators with the same result.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Maybe if I explain my goal. I use an off the shelf retail application that runs in a browser. When a certain product is purchased there needs to be a certain comment made on the invoice. To speed this up beyond copying and pasting from a text file, I want a printed QR code on the desk that can be scanned as needed. No mistakes then either. I can get it to work fine as one line of words, but I need line breaks between paragraphs. It searches the google downloads after the first break.

Comment: I think I need to try %0D rather than %0A. I will try this tomorrow when I have the scanner.

Comment: I'm voting to close, because it was caused by a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `%0D` rather than `%0A`.